How to pass variable while calling macros in pre hook
I have a variable and I want to pass it to a macros, I call the macros itself in pre_Hook
{% set v_name = 'BOS' %}

{{
    config(
      pre_hook=[ 
       "{{marcos_test(v_name)}}"
          ]
      
    )
}} 



it works, but in the macros itself it does not see the value of the variable
How can I call marcos in pre_hook so it will see the value of the variable ?
Global variable in dbt_project.yml file they are not suitable because I need a dynamic variable
someone please help

One way to achieve this is to use concatenation. You can use ~ sign for concatenation in Jinja.
Note, your macro most probably expects string as an input, then you need to add ' quotes around concatenation (...'" ~ v_name ~ "'...).
{% set v_name = 'BOS' %}

{{
    config(
      pre_hook=[ 
       "{{ marcos_test('" ~ v_name ~ "') }}"
          ]
      
    )
}} 

